# How to create a trigger in the database that does'nt allow operators CREATE to execute at night?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I want to create a trigger in the database that does'nt allow operators CREATE to execute at night.

I've tried 'CREATE TRIGGER', but in the documentation there is no CREATE operator, only INSERT and others.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need an [event trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-triggers.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need an `EVENT TRIGGER`. The trigger function can restrict the operation based on timings. I have given you just a sample. You may use the proper condition as needed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pr_create_obj_func()
RETURNS event_trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
if ( extract( hour from clock_timestamp() )  between 0 and 6 ) then
   raise EXCEPTION '% : This operation cannot be performed at night',tg_tag;
end if;
END;
$$;
```

The event trigger must then be defined as

```
CREATE EVENT TRIGGER
  tg_no_night_create ON ddl_command_end
   WHEN  TAG in  ('CREATE TABLE')
EXECUTE PROCEDURE pr_create_obj_func();
```

The various tags that can be specified in the `IN` clause for the actual events to which trigger is to be fired are listed [**here**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/event-trigger-matrix.html)